# What is the relation between Spark's whole-stage Java code generator modules

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am exploring the whole-stage Java code generation feature of Spark and notice there are several components there. There is an execution engine and a compiler.

Could you clarify the relation between all the components? the moving parts I recognized are:

1. Catalyst for the query optimization
2. [Tungsten](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/05/23/apache-spark-as-a-compiler-joining-a-billion-rows-per-second-on-a-laptop.html) for execution engine?
3. Janino compiler

Are those the standard today? are there any other parts I didn't mention?

What is the execution flow between Spark and those components and the components between themselves?

Comment: For someone who vote to close: Come on, relation between components is not too broad in my opinion. OP Does not ask for detailed information, but only how 3 components relates, I think it's quite short to answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query "flow" is:

- user creates some Dataset - now it has only logicalPlan
- during action evaluation, Spark uses Analyzer and Catalyst for tree manipulation
- next, Spark uses [Catalyst](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html) to Optimize analyzedPlan, running optimization rules in batches until plan is "stable" or we have max iterations.
- during physical planning, Spark uses Janino to compile all steps (stages) that were marked as "WholeStageCodegen" during optimization. Note that compilation is a part of Tungsten Project, as described [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/28/project-tungsten-bringing-spark-closer-to-bare-metal.html). Other part of this project is for example new binary representation of data in memory
- at the end, Spark execution engine executes generated code.

Note that "Catalyst" was created as a Tree Manipulation Framework, now often we say "Catalyst" for whole optimizer. Also Tungsten is just a project in which some features were developed, but now we say that execution engine that uses features from Tungsten is called Tungsten

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, I know you were digging into "what Catalyst is", please share information if I wrote everything well